# casting IDataReader to DbDataReader

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I'm using `SqlDataReader` on my project to read data From DB to send it to Web service.I had this method to read company data `companyID` and `companyName` I have a casting problem:

```
public static DbDataReader GetCompanies()
{
    DbDataReader dr = null;
    DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();

    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    try
    {
        dr = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteReader(comm);
        dr.Read();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return dr;


}

//ExecuteReader DAL
     public static IDataReader ExecuteReader(DbCommand command)
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Utilities.LogError(ex);
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }

            }
```

Problem:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.IDataReader' to 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the return-type of either your GetCompanies() method (preferred) or of your DAL ExecuteReader() method.